# TypeError: command.execute is not a function when catching an error. Also, cooldown doesn't work. On Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, command

I've been working on a Discord bot for a while and have implemented a cooldown command for a while too. It never works, and today i decided that i will try to fix it.

At first, it kept sending me an error message saying `TypeError: command.execute is not a function` and an error message on the channel, so i just removed `catch (err)` so it wont send that annoying message. But of course, doing that is perhaps the equivalent of removing a scratched limb.

Now that more people uses my bot, i was trying to rework on the cooldown feature, which is located on `../events/guild/message.js` and it goes like this:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const cooldowns = new Map();

module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
  
    const prefix = message.content.includes("nabe ") ? "nabe " : "n!"
  
    if (message.content.indexOf(prefix) !== 0) return;
  
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
    const cmd = client.commands.get(command) || client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));
  
    if(message.channel.type === "dm")return message.channel.send("you can't use commands on dm")
  
    if(cmd){
      cmd.execute(client, message, args, Discord);
    }else return

    if(!cooldowns.has(command.name)){
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }

    const current_time = Date.now();
    const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldown_amount = (command.cooldown) * 1000;

    
    if(time_stamps.has(message.author.id)){
        const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;

        if(current_time < expiration_time){
            const time_left = (expiration_time - current_time) / 1000;

            return message.reply(`wait **${time_left.toFixed(1)}** more seconds to do ${command.name} again.`).then(msg => { msg.delete({ timeout: 7000 }) });
        }
    }

    
    time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
    
    setTimeout(() => time_stamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldown_amount);
    
    try{
        command.execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord);
    } catch (err){
        message.reply("There was an error trying to execute this command.");
        console.log(err);
    }

}
```

How it was implemented on each command files:

```
module.exports = {
    info: {
        name: "command name",
        description: "command description",
        cooldown: 30,
    },
    async execute(client, message, args, Discord) {
              /*code here*/
}
```

By the way, i got most of this code from CodeLyon on youtube, and [here's the sourcebin.](https://sourceb.in/3ZKvtEUkU9)

Everytime i executed a command it will return the `TypeError: command.execute is not a function` error and an error message on the channel. I am aware that some people said that `command.execute` does not exist, but it works on the tutorial video, and i don't know any alternatives. And it probably won't even fix the cooldown anyway.

I will definitely really appreciate it if anybody can find a solution.

NodeJS 16.13.0, NPM 8.1.0, DiscordJS 12.5.3, Heroku server.

Answer (score -1):

> I am aware that some people said that `command.execute` does not exist

And they would be right. As you can see in your defined command:

```js
module.exports = {
    info: {
        name: "command name",
        description: "command description",
        cooldown: 30,
    },
```

You did not appear to specify an `execute` function in the command body. If you want to run the command, you need to do that:

```js
module.exports = {
    info: {
        name: "command name",
        description: "command description",
        cooldown: 30,
        execute: (client, message, args, Discord) => {
            // command logic goes here
        }
    },
```

P.S I believe the sourcebin tutorial that you linked also included an `execute` function:

[image]

Comment: Actually, i do have an execute in every command files. I didn't put it on the question, my bad.  `async execute(client, message, args, Discord)` otherwise the commands just wouldn't work if i don't have an execute on the command files.

Comment: @dimactavish Please provide full details when asking a question.

Comment: I've edited the question. It should now have sufficient details, right?
and didn't i say that "more people uses my bot"? if it doesn't work at all to begin with, why would anybody be able to use it.

Comment: @dimactavish Your question regards a syntax error with your code, which happened to be supplemented by the incomplete picture that you provided. Thus, I came to a conclusion that that was the problem you were having. I am also unaware of what features are included in your bot. You say 'people use my bot', but in what way other than commands? And neither do I know how your codebase is structured.

Comment: My codes are structured akin to the ones from the tutorials that i first saw, which is CodeLyon's. In what usage can other people even use my bot for other than it's commands? Everything just works fine except for the cooldown and the last part with `command.execute`.

Comment: Nevermind, it was just a mistype. replacing `command` with `cmd` fixed it. The cooldown still has a problem, though.

Comment: @dimactavish Please open another question as this thread is getting quite bloated.